# $\forall$ $x,y \in X$, if $f(x)=f(y)$ and $f((x+y)/2)\geq f(y)$. Then is f quasiconcave?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

$\forall$ $x,y \in X$ s.t. $f(x)=f(y)$ and $f((x+y)/2)\geq f(y)$. Then is f quasiconcave? Proof or Counterexample.

Comment: The condition $f(x) = f(y)$ for all $x, y$ means that $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: f is not a constant function.

Comment: Then you need to correct your statement, in this form only a constant function can satisfy the conditions.

Comment: I think it might mean $f(x)\geq f(y)$?

Comment: But $f(x)$=$f(y)$ is already given. I'm curious about quasiconcavity.